# Incron doesn't do anything

Tags: centos7, incron

I intstalled on a new vm with centos 7 incron.

I try to make it work but a simple command does nothing.

incrontab -e :

```
/home/test IN_CLOSE_WRITE touch "$@/$#.new"
```

nothing special

When i watch the log cron i see this :

```
May 13 11:40:57 Minions incrond[2785]: (root) CMD (touch "/home/test/test.new")
```

but nothing is created in the directory

```
[root@Minions test]# ll
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 13 mai   11:40 test
```

Do you have an idea what is wrong ?

Comment: I have this exact same problem, incrond installed and running, and I see the commands in the cron log, but its like they're not actually run

Answer (score 0):

I just del quote like this :

```
/home/test IN_CLOSE_WRITE touch $@/$#.new
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather old but... maybe your incrond service isn't running.

```sh
# systemctl enable incrond.service
# systemctl start incrond.service
```